# How many independent measurement of CPU-time are required such that the difference $|\bar{X} - \mu|<0.1$ with probability $0.9$ at least?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

> The actual required CPU-time of a workstation session is assumed (due to a long-term study) as a
>   random variable with unknown expected value $\mu$ and known variance
>   $\sigma^2=6.25[s^2]$. How many independent measurement of CPU-time
>   are needed such that with probability of at least $0.9$, you have that
>   the difference $|\bar{X}-\mu|$ is less than $0.1$?

This is task from old exam with different teacher. I ask my teacher and he say he don't show this example in class but give me two method for solve it: **Central limit theorem** and **Chebyshev's inequality**. This already help me much and I try solve like this:

I use central limit theorem:

We have that $$\sqrt{n} (\bar{X}-\mu) \text{ for } n \rightarrow \infty \text { is approximately standard normally distributed}$$

Now assume we have very big $n$ such that approximation mistake is very small so we don't need to keep it in mind. Then we can do

$$P(|\bar{X}-\mu|) < \varepsilon) = P(\sqrt{n}|\bar{X}-\mu|<\sqrt{n} \varepsilon)=P(-\sqrt{n}\varepsilon< \sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)< \sqrt{n} \varepsilon) \\ \approx \Phi(\sqrt{n} \varepsilon)- \Phi(-\sqrt{n}\varepsilon) = 2\Phi(\sqrt{n}\varepsilon)-1$$

Now insert $\varepsilon= 0.1$ in inequality $P(|\bar{X}-\mu|<\varepsilon)\geq 0.9$ then we have

$$2\Phi(0.1 \cdot \sqrt{n})-1 \geq 0.9 \Leftrightarrow \Phi(0.1 \cdot \sqrt{n}) \geq 0.95$$

And from this step I don't know how finish it :/

Can you tell me if this is correct till here and how to finish it? I really think I almost got it but something is missing..

But actually I'm more interested to know how you would do this with Chebyshev? I tried it already but also not sure if correct (see my comment of *karakfa*'s answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chebyshev inequality won't help you here.  With some overall assumptions you can use the normal approximation and work from the z-table.

The sample size you'll come up with should be

$$
n = (\frac{z_{\alpha/2} \sigma}{E})^2
$$

for 90% CI, $z_{\alpha/2} \approx 1.65$, and $E$ is given as $0.1$, $\sigma^2=6.25$

$ n \approx 1700$

Comment: I think it work with Chebyshev also I try all day today:

Because we have $var(\bar{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ we have that $$P(|\bar{X}-\mu|\geq \varepsilon) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{n \varepsilon^2}$$

make this in complement we have $$P(|\bar{X}-\mu| < \varepsilon) \geq 1-\frac{\sigma^2}{n \varepsilon^2}$$

Comment: Now we insert $\varepsilon = 0.1$ and because RHS of last expression in my previous comment is greater then $0.9$ then is also LHS greater then it. This mean our $n$ we looking for is big enough for satisfy inequality $P(|\bar{X}-\mu| < 0.1) \geq 0.9$

Comment: It don't work like that really?

Comment: Yes, you can follow that as well, but the value will not be tight compared to CLT approximation.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer and comments! :)

Bounty will be for you.