# What's the probability that at least one passenger gets no seat?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

> Two airplane companies respectively use one airplane (to go from
>   country A to country B). There are in total $1000$ people randomly
>   choose the airplane, respectively with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.
>
> The company offers planes with $510$ seats for passengers. What's the
>   probability that at least one passenger gets no seat?

I think theorem of De Moivre Laplace is good to use here:

First of we have $P(X \geq 510 +1) = p$

Then

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\leq x\right) = \Phi(x)$$

$$P(X \geq 510+1) = 1-P(X \leq 510) = 1-\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \leq \frac{510}{\sqrt{1000 \cdot \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2})}}\right)  \\ = 1-\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \leq \frac{510}{5\sqrt{10}}\right) \approx 1-\Phi\left(\frac{510}{5\sqrt{10}}\right) \leq p$$

But from here I don't know how continue and if correct till here? I need read value from table but I don't know how and find it for this high value?

Comment: Note:  it isn't all that hard to just use the binomial distribution.  With a computer it is easy to do it exactly...though cutting it off around $X=600$ makes little difference).  If you are going to use the normal approximation, you should take care to use the continuity correction...that is certainly significant.

Comment: Numerically:  via the binomial distribution I get $0.253330021$.  If I use the normal approximation WITH continuity correction I get $0.253320096$ so quite close.  WITHOUT the correction (as in your attempt) I get $0.263544628$.

Comment: @lulu What tool you use for calculation can you pls show me thank you for all comment lulu because my calculator don't work for big number

Comment: I just did it in Excel.   Wolfram alpha (available for free online) could certainly do it as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a error in your calculation:

$$P(X \geq 510+1) = 1-P(X \leq 510) = 1-\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \leq \frac{\color{red}{\mathbf{10}}}{\sqrt{1000 \cdot \frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2})}}\right)  \\ = 1-\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \leq \frac{10}{5\sqrt{10}}\right) \approx 1-\Phi\left(\frac{10}{5\sqrt{10}}\right) \approx 1-\Phi\left(0.632 \right) = 1- 0.7357 = 0.2643$$

Comment: Thank you! but why there must be $10$ instead how you get it?

Comment: Ok I have wrong note on my paper the reason you have $10$ is because $510-1000 \cdot \frac{1}{2}=10$

Comment: When you have interest for other question please answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611250/how-many-independent-measurement-of-cpu-time-are-required-such-that-the-differen/2611349#2611349

Because I think it will work with Chebychev but people who answer say it don't work..

Comment: Both this answer and the original question ignore the continuity correction and calculate only the probability that a specific plane is filled. Both of these factors are significant (particularly the latter), making your answer way off.

Comment: Of course Iknow what you mean Jason, but in this Case I interpreted it intentionally just the way I calculated it because most of the tasks in this area are meant and formulated this way

Answer (score 3):

The exact answer is:

$$P = 1 - \frac{\sum_{j=490}^{510}{1000 \choose j}}{2^{1000}}$$

Pick one plane. There needs to be no fewer than $490$ and no more than $510$ passengers on that plane. The sum takes care of those cases; you want all the other cases.

Comment: Thank you for answer! You know program that can do big calculation? My calculator don't worked because too big numbers, I think exponent is very high for my calculator.

Comment: WolframAlpha can evaluate this easily, leading to an answer of approximately 0.50666.